# Function to check if two values in a column are equal and if one of their corresponding row values is equal

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains `Raw file`s and `Sequences` as columns. I want to check the `Sequences` column to find any duplicate sequences and for all the duplicates to check that their `Raw file` is also the same. This is what it looks like:

| Raw file  |  Sequences  | otherdata1 | otherdata2 |

| HU_932 |     BLAST    |      **&        *|*       (&         |

| WR_235 |     HELLO   |      #(@       |       #@*       |

| HU_932 |      BLAST    |     #@(       |        (#)        |

| HU_932 |      CHART   |     $&@      |        %#*       |

| RT_329 |        BLAST    |      ^*)       |        @$#     |

So in the example above, I want to be able to select only the first and third rows because those are the only rows in which the `Sequences` are the same and the `Raw file`s are the same.

In my actual data, the sequence lengths are greater than 15 characters so I can't use the Excel conditional formatting for duplicates. I thought of using the EXACT and MATCH functions but I would also need to know the cell with which it matched in order to compare its `Raw file` with the matched cell's `Raw file`.

Comment: You have been here long enough to know you need to show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both `Raw file` and `Sequences` on the current row are replicated, that also implies that the `Sequences` on the current row is duplicated elsewhere. Hence you can reduce it to only 1 criterion.

Try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)>1
```

I assume `Raw file` is in column A and `Sequences` is in column B. The other 2 are irrelevant because there are no criteria on them.

Comment: Thanks so much! Now I'm able to use the True/False values to filter the rows that I need :)

Answer (score 0):

In Excel 2013 there does not seem to be the 15 character limit mentioned, so if filtering both columns for the appropriate colour repeated pairs may be selected.

An alternative might be to create a PivotTable and observe (or drill down on) values greater than `1`:

[image: SO33135830 example]